# Nested foreach optimizing

Tags: performance, loops, nested

I have 3 foreach loop nested together, which could be an issue performance wise. Is there a way to make it more efficient?

Made up example:

```
List<User> users;
List<Friend> friends;

foreach(user in users)
{
    //Find if a user have a friend
    foreach(friend in friends)
    {

        foreach(userFriend in user.friendList)
        {
            //find match
            if(friend.name.Equals(userFriend.name)){

                //do stuff
                break;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using `for` in place of `foreach` can improve performance substantially, according to [this blog posting](http://blog.kzarczynski.com/2015/08/for-vs-foreach-follow-up/). Maybe worthwhile to try both methods and see.

Comment: Well what does this mean, doesn't the non-emptyness of a `friendList` already imply that a user has friends? No need to search anything. Or, if what you're doing is weirder than it looks like, made a hashset with the names of the friendList things and then for every friend ask the hashset whether their name is in it.

Comment: The example may not be the best :). But what I wanted to know, is if you got a List with a List inside and you need to compare some variable with another List. Is there a way to make a case like this better than 3 nested loops of any kind.